# Python Google Slides API How to replace rectangle with an image?

Tags: python, google-slides-api

I have a google slide presentation with a slide and a rectangle. The rectangle serves as a placeholder and will be replaced by an image.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/11/using-google-slides-api-with-python.html) on how to replace the shape with image. It works but the size of the image is not the same as the rectangle. How can I replace the rectangle with an image and use the size of rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to replace a shape including a placeholder text with an image by keeping the shape size. Namely, you want to change the size of the inputted image with ignoring the aspect ratio of the image.
- You want to achieve this using Slides API with Python.

### Issue and workaround:

In order to replace a shape with an image using Slides API, ReplaceAllShapesWithImageRequest of batchUpdate method is used. Here, the patterns for replacing are as follows. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#imagereplacemethod)

> CENTER_INSIDE: Scales and centers the image to fit within the bounds of the original shape and maintains the image's aspect ratio. The rendered size of the image may be smaller than the size of the shape. This is the default method when one is not specified.

> CENTER_CROP:  Scales and centers the image to fill the bounds of the original shape. The image may be cropped in order to fill the shape. The rendered size of the image will be the same as the original shape.

Unfortunately, from the above patterns, it is found that in this case, your goal cannot be achieved. As another approach, even when CreateImageRequest is used, the official document of CreateImageRequest of Slides API says as follows.

> elementProperties: When the aspect ratio of the provided size does not match the image aspect ratio, the image is scaled and centered with respect to the size in order to maintain the aspect ratio. The provided transform is applied after this operation.

Unfortunately, it seems that when Slides API is used, the aspect ratio of the image is kept, and the image size cannot be changed by ignoring the aspect ratio. I would like to propose reporting this as a future request to [Google issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

From this situation, as a workaround, I would like to propose using Google Apps Script. When Google Apps Script is used, the image can be replaced with a shape by ignoring the aspect ratio of the image. The sample script is as follows.

### Usage:

#### Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Slides, and save the script.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const { pageObjectId, placeholderText, imageUrl } = e.parameter;
  const slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlideById(pageObjectId);
  if (!slide) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("No slide.");
  }
  const shapes = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getText().asString().trim() == placeholderText);
  if (shapes.length == 0) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("No shapes.");
  }
  shapes.forEach(shape => {
    const width = shape.getWidth();
    const height = shape.getHeight();
    const top = shape.getTop();
    const left = shape.getLeft();
    shape.replaceWithImage(imageUrl).setWidth(width).setHeight(height).setTop(top).setLeft(left);
  });
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");
}
```

#### Deploy Web Apps.

In order to request from Python script, the above script is deployed as Web Apps. The detailed information can be seen in [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Please set this using the new IDE of the script editor.

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. When "The Web App requires you to authorize access to your data." is shown, please click "Authorize access" button. And, please authorize the scopes.
8. Copy the URL of the Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`. This URL is used for executing Google Apps Script.

#### Testing.

In order to request Web Apps from Python script, the following sample script is used. When you test this, please set your Web Apps URL, `imageUrl`, `pageObjectId`, and `placeholderText`, respectively.

```py
import requests

url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
query = {
    "imageUrl": "https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png", # This is a sample image URL.
    "pageObjectId": "###",
    "placeholderText": "{{sample}}",
}
res = requests.get(url, params=query)
print(res.text)
```

When this script is run using a sample Google Slide, the following result is obtained. It is found that a shape is replaced with a sample image with keeping the size of the shape by ignoring the aspect ratio of the image.

[image]

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)